# Ext.Ajax.request not working in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, extjs

Need help with this block of code...

```
dummyData = [{name: "test"},{foo: "bar"}];

var postData = {};
postData.csrfi = csrfi;
postData.data   = Ext.JSON.encode(dummyData);


Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:        UrlGenerator.getControllerActionUrl('RfqSE', 'sendQuotations', { media: 'json'} ),
    params: postData,
    callback: function(options, success, response) {
        var showErrorMsg    = true;

        if (success) {
            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

            if (obj && obj.success === true) {
                showErrorMsg = false;
            }
        }

        if (showErrorMsg) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("error", "some error has occured");
        }

        callback.call();
    }
});
```

...for some reason params are not sent to the server side, it's not working only on IE 7,8... Haven't tried 9+.. On chrome and mozilla works as excepted.... Url is fine,params are fine also...
EDIT: I'm using 4.2 ExtJS
Any help is much much appreciated...

Comment: Probably because you're double encoding everything. By passing `postData` as an object, Ext will already encode it. IE could be choking on that. Just pass the object in.

Comment: No.. sadly this way doesn't work either...

But just i little update in question... When i add 'params' or 'jsonData' as param in Ajax object it doesn't work... Even if i pass simple object as {foo:'bar'}

Answer (score 0):

Use 'jsonData' instead of 'params'

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        jsonData: postData,
        method: 'POST',
        success:{//Do sonething},
        failure:{//Do sonething},
        scope: this,
        timeout: 100000
    });
```

Comment: Tried it.. This way it doesn't send data at all.. And it is not even in docs :O